# Administrative theme doesn't work for users who aren't administrators

Tags: 8

I have a theme for the frontend and I use "seven" for the backend as I set it on `admin/appearance`.

I created a new role: "power user", which is a limited access to the different content types. The "power user" role has access to the "View the administration theme" permission.

I created a new user, assigned it to the "power user" role and when I edit a content then the page is displayed by my frontend theme instead of the admin theme.
I tested it on 2 different drupal systems with same results: 8.3.1 and 8.3.4.
The admin theme works for the "administrator" role.

[image]

[image: drupal admin theme not working for power_user role]

Any idea how can I fix it?

Is this a bug, or there is something else that I forgot to set up?

Comment: Because they don't have permission to view the admin theme.

Comment: They have "View the administration theme" permission: `power_user[view the administration theme] = 1`. What else do they need?

Comment: What does that mean? Is it checked off in the admin?

Comment: I took a screenshot about the current permissions setting. You can see that the "View the administration theme" permission is assigned to the "power user" role.

Comment: Make sure you've checked the "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" checkbox on the Appearance admin page (where you set the admin theme)

Comment: Hi Jaypan, I attached another image to my question. You can see that that checkbox is already selected.